# Sort by count of associated has_many model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Got the following models

```
class Document
  has_many :document_tag_links
  has_many :document_tags, through: :document_tag_links 

class DocumentTag
  has_many :document_tag_links
  has_many :documents, through: :document_tag_links

class DocumentTagLink
  belongs_to :document
  belongs_to :document_tag
```

Now, I'm trying to sort DocumentTags by how many documents they are associated with. I've tried the following:

```
scope :top10, -> {
  joins(:document_tag_links).
  select("documents.*, count(document_id) as documents_count").
  group("document_id").
  order("documents_count desc")
}
```

But that gives me the following error:

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "documents"
   LINE 1: SELECT documents.*, count(document_id) AS...
                  ^
   : SELECT documents.*, count(document_id) AS documents_count FROM "document_tags" INNER JOIN "document_tag_links" ON "document_tag_links"."document_tag_id" = "document_tags"."id" GROUP BY document_id  ORDER BY documents_count desc
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You're trying to get columns from the documents table but there is no 'FROM documents' clause because you're setting the scope on DocumentTag which creates a 'FROM document_tags'.

Comment: shouldn't the join take care of that? How would I get this to work?

Comment: You're only joining document_tags and document_tag_links. Why do you need documents.* anyway, you're trying to fetch the tags and count of each tag.

Comment: I'm trying to sort the tags based on how many documents are associated with them.

Comment: `scope :top10, -> {
  joins(:document_tag_links).
  select("document_tags.*, count(document_id) as documents_count").
  group("document_id").
  order("documents_count desc")
}`

Comment: Had to change .group("document_id") to .group("document_tags.id") and then it worked. Please add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Good to hear, have added an answer.

Comment: How about adding a counter cache on the tables and order by the count? by this you do not have to join table and write such as complicated query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution after discussion in comments.

```
scope :top10, -> {
  joins(:document_tag_links)
  .select("document_tags.*, count(document_id) as documents_count")
  .group("document_tags_id")
  .order("documents_count desc") }
```